# Alphanumeric string pattern with apostrophe allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate name field which excepts only alphanumeric, apostrophe and a dot(.) For example, it should allow the string `abc's home99`,`St. Mary's Hospital` but I don't want the string starting with any of the special characters or ending with it for example `'abc` or `abc'` or `g_abc 56gfhg` or `abc 56gfhg.`.

i have used

```
stringPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9']*$/;
```

pattern but it allows apostrophe anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 3):

try this regex:

```
\w(\w|'|\ )*\w
```

you can test it here: http://regexpal.com/

but it requires the username to be at least 2 characters long

Comment: @Eineki I tested your regex and it matches every single character (every character is a match on its own). thats not right. my regex matches the whole username if it (the username) has the right form

Comment: just added the \w| to your regexp to solve the two chars issue. The complete expression should be something like this: `^(\w|(\w(\w|'|\ )*\w))$`

Comment: using ^(\w|(\w(\w|'|\ )*\w))$ this solved my problem

Comment: @Eineki hey hi my requirement is changed a little.. now i also need to add .(dot) in between string, same as it excepts apostrophe. how to achive it in your given expression? also it excepts '_' in between the string.. i dont want it as well

Answer (score 2):

```
var pattern = /^[^'][a-zA-Z0-9' ]*[^']$/;

console.log(pattern.exec("abc's home99"));
console.log(pattern.exec("'abc"));
console.log(pattern.exec("abc'"));
```

**Output**

```
[ 'abc\'s home99', index: 0, input: 'abc\'s home99' ]
null
null
```

In this Regular Expression, we say that, first character should not be `'` (`^[^']`) and the last character should not be `'` (`[^']$`). You already had the rest :)

Comment: hey its excepting "abc." or "abc," or ",abc" strings..which i dont want. i dont want any special characters other than apostrophe

Comment: @Sonia That was not part of the question :) Please list all the invalid characters in the question.

Comment: hi ^(\w|(\w(\w|'|\ )*\w))$ this helped me. i dint wanted any special characters rather than apostrophe. sorry will edit the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
^\w+(?:[.' ]*\w+)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

^\w+(?:[.' ]*\w+)*$

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION

----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [.' ]*                   any character of: '.', ''', ' ' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [A-Z,a-z,0-9,`-', ]* in pattern attribute of html input element. It will allow Letters,spaces,numbers,apostrophe and hyphen.